# How do I find solutions for $e^{f(x)}=1$ where $f$ is the complex function $f=2 i\pi (\Gamma(x)+1)/x$?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, prime-numbers

How do I find solutions for $e^{f(x)}=n$?  Specifically:

$$e^{2 i\pi (\Gamma(x)+1)/x}=1: x\in\mathbb{N}>4$$

There should be infinitely many solutions.

Sorry, this is a later clarification of what I meant by the question: I'm wondering if by calculus the solutions to the meromorphic function can be found, rather than finding the solutions by modular arithmetic (and Wilson's theorem).  At $e^{f(x)}=1$, I am thinking the imaginary part equals zero and therefore this would be a minimum of $\sin^2(2\pi(\Gamma(x)+1)/x)$.

And the same can be said of the real part:  $\cos^2(2\pi(\Gamma(x)+1)/x)=0$ - which again must be a minimum.  It would seem solutions to these simultaneous equations will yield primes but it is the differentiation of these two functions which is beyond me.

Can this approach can lead to a polynomial that generates prime numbers?

Comment: Is $f(x)$ assumed to be holomorphic? Entire? We have that $f(x)=n_x\pi i$, but since this set is discrete, if $f(x)$ is continous, we have that $f(x)=n\pi i$, so is constant.

Comment: @PaxKivimae your simplification to $n\pi i$ eliminates infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @PaxKivimae yes, it is holomorphic for $x>4$ and it's a complex function.  I'm not sure whether it's entire but the function is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You may use Wilson's theorem: [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem)

Comment: I created the equation using Wilson's theorem!  But well spotted.  I'm looking for other approaches to solve.

Comment: I was in fact close to write in my answer that it was most likely the intention of the problem-setter that one should look up Wilson's theorem ;-) I don't think it is the most economical way to find primes, though. And a part from redoing the proof of Wilson, I don't see a reasonable way to find another approach, but who knows...

Comment: I was wondering if the real part of $e^f(x)$ be differentiated and the maxima which coincide with natural numbers found?  This would find solutions would it not?  I wonder if this function translates into a set of diophantine equations.